# responseJson is undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native

Here is my code for fetching my JSON data from my API. What I'm trying to do is print the names of the various medications in my Flatlist and then make that object clickable so I can display more information about it on the next page. I can receive the JSON data correctly, but my problem comes with displaying it. My first alert displays what I have in my medications array (two medications), but when I try to display those names, I get "undefined", but there is clearly a field called "name" that is associated with data.

My flatlist doesn't throw any errors, it just doesn't display anything. I'm not sure what else to try at this point.

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Button,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  ActivityIndicator,
  AsyncStorage
} from 'react-native'
import Swipeout from 'react-native-swipeout';

import { goToAuth } from '../../helpers/Navigation'
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';

import { USER_KEY, USERID_KEY, USERNAME, PASSWORD, API_URL } from '../../helpers/Config'
import { refreshToken } from '../../helpers/Helper'

export default class Medication extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { isLoading: true, dataSource: [] }
    this.getMedications();
  }



  static get options() {
    return {
      topBar: {
        title: {
          text: 'Medication'
        },
      }
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {

  }

  getMedications = async () => {
    // used to assign the medication to the specific individual
    const userID = await AsyncStorage.getItem(USERID_KEY);

    // used to access the protected links
    const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem(USER_KEY);


    fetch(API_URL + '/medications/all/' + userID, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'x-access-token': userToken
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        alert(responseJson.status);
        alert(responseJson.message);
        // displays all medication data
        alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson.data.medications)); 
        // should display the names, displays undefined
        alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson.data.medications.name));
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  logout = async () => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.removeItem(USER_KEY)
      goToAuth()
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('error signing out...: ', err)
    }
  }

  render() {

    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 20 }}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      )
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>



        <FlatList>
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.data.medications.name}</Text>}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        </FlatList>

        <Button
          onPress={this.logout}
          title="Sign Out"
        />
        <Button
          onPress={() => {
            Navigation.push(this.props.componentId, {
              component: {
                name: 'MedicationDetailScreen',
              }
            });
          }}
          title="View Medication Detail Screen"
        />
        <Button
          onPress={() => {
            Navigation.push(this.props.componentId, {
              component: {
                name: 'AddMedicationScreen',
              }
            });
          }}
          title="View Add Medication Screen"
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
})
```

[image: JSON Response alert in Android Emulator]

[image: JSON Response in Postman]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) I see the `data` property of  is an array. You should `setState` of `dataSource` like this

```
this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
      dataSource: responseJson.data.medications,
    });
```

and because `responseJson.data.medications` is an array, you can't get the `name` property of an item. You must identify which item you wanna get `name` first. It must be

```
alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson.data.medications[0].name)) // For example the first item
```

Comment: Oh that was pretty simple. It's always the simple things I overlook.